# Babel: two languages, active shorthands

Tags: punctuation, babel, shorthands

I'd like to use multiple languages in my document (babel), and both `ngerman` and `british` should have the nice shorthands active ("`   and `"'`). The british language environment should turn "` into “ and "' into ”. The main language should stay ngerman.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% \defineshorthand[british]{"`}{\glqq}
% \defineshorthand[british]{"'}{\grqq}
\addto\extrasbritish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}}

\begin{document}
"`Guten Tag"'

\begin{otherlanguage*}{british}
"`Hello tag"'
\end{otherlanguage*}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: bad quotes]

expected output:

[image]

I feel totally stupid, this seems to be a pre-beginner's question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation is far from clear, but I don't think there's much more to do than redefining the shorthand to do specific tasks depending on the current language:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\addto\extrasbritish{%
  \languageshorthands{ngerman}%
  \useshorthands*{"}%
}

\defineshorthand{"`}{\iflanguage{ngerman}{\glqq}{\lq\lq}}
\defineshorthand{"'}{\iflanguage{ngerman}{\grqq}{\rq\rq}}

\begin{document}
"`Guten Tag"'

\begin{otherlanguage*}{british}
"`Hello tag"'
\end{otherlanguage*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem is in the fact that you're importing the shorthands from `ngerman`; for instance this would work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\useshorthands*{"}
\addto\extrasbritish{%
  \languageshorthands{british}%
}

\defineshorthand[british]{"`}{\lq\lq}
\defineshorthand[british]{"'}{\rq\rq}

\begin{document}
"`Guten Tag"'

\begin{otherlanguage*}{british}
"`Hello tag"'
\end{otherlanguage*}
\end{document}
```

Of course, the other German shorthands would be lost.