# Why doesn't \nolinebreak work in this case?

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

When I have something like:

```
(Some-)Thing
```

at the end of the line, LaTeX always breaks after the '-', even when I use:

```
(Some-\nolinebreak)Thing
```

I do know about solutions like using `\mbox{}`, but I ask for an explanation, not a way to work around, but if there's a "better" way to do this, I'm grateful for any recommondations!

I also tried `\nolinebreak[4]` which although should be the same.

Comment: Because the `-` is set as `\hyphenchar`. The `\hyphenchar` has two meanings in TeX: 1) it is printed when`\-` primitive (or automatic hyphenation) is activated at the point where line is broken and 2) if it is used in the middle of the word then `\discretionary{}{}{}` is added. And the second meaning is the reason of the described behaviour. No matter that the `\penalty10000` follows after such character.

Comment: Ah okay, Iso basically the `\nolinebreak` has no effect as it doesn't break *after* but *at* the '-'? Well learned something new! Thanks for the explanation. (Why don't you move it to the answers?^^)

Comment: Also `(Some\mbox{-})Thing`, which doesn't require any extra package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `babel` in German, you can use `"~` that produces exactly what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}(Some"~)Thing}

\end{document}
```

The `\parbox{0pt}` is for inviting TeX to break wherever possible, but if you try you'll see that no break at all is taken.

[image]

What `"~` does is, basically, issuing `\mbox{-}`.

If you don't use `ngerman`, but still use `babel`, you could import the German shorthands (see [Babel: two languages, active shorthands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238748/babel-two-languages-active-shorthands)) or, more simply, define a macro:

```
\newcommand{\ppref}[1]{(#1\mbox{-})} % Parenthesized PREFix
```

and input the text as

```
\ppref{Some}Thing
```

---

The reason why `\nolinebreak` is ineffective is that `-` in normal text inserts a discretionary break after it, so typing

```
(Some-\nolinebreak)Thing
```

is the same as typing

```
(Some-\discretionary{}{}{}\nolinebreak)Thing
```

and TeX is allowed to break lines at discretionaries. The penalty that follows cannot change this. There is no `\undiscretionary` similar to `\unskip` or `\unpenalty`.

The `\nobreakdash` macro of `amsmath` just encloses in an `\mbox` the `-`, `--` or `---` that follows, so typing

```
(Some\nobreakdash-)Thing
```

is exactly the same as typing

```
(Some\mbox{-})Thing
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `amsmath` package, you could type

```
(Some\nobreakdash-)Thing
```

A full MWE (minimum working example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for '\nobreakdash' macro
\usepackage[textwidth=1mm]{geometry} % set a very narrow measure
\begin{document}
\hspace{0pt}(Some-)Thing  % this will produce a line break

\hspace{0pt}(Some\nobreakdash-)Thing % no linebreak here...
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is definitely a cool macro! Weird that one needs a maths package, but I have them anyway :D